Why are messages lost after consumer recovery in RabbitMQ/MassTransit publisher-consumer setup?
In my MassTransit + RabbitMQ setup, I have a publisher that both sends and subscribes to events, and a separate consumer application. When the consumer is down and the publisher sends and processes an event, the message is not delivered to the consumer after it comes back online. It seems RabbitMQ considers the message as already processed since the publisher consumed it.
Important note: When both applications are running, the message delivery works correctly and both applications consume the messages as expected. The issue only occurs in the recovery scenario described above.
Expected behavior: Messages should be delivered to all subscribed consumers, even if one consumer (the publisher in this case) has already processed it. When the consumer application recovers, it should receive messages that were published during its downtime.
The configuration is the same for both applications:
using System.Reflection;
using MassTransit;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using SharedKernel.Communication.Events;
using SharedKernel.Utils;

namespace SharedKernel.Communication.Extensions;

public static class MassTransitServicesExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddMassTransit(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        IConfiguration config,
        Assembly consumersAssembly,
        string applicationName
    )
    {
        services.AddMassTransit(busConfigurator =>
        {
            busConfigurator.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

            busConfigurator.AddConsumers(consumersAssembly);

            busConfigurator.UsingRabbitMq(
                (context, configurator) =>
                {
                    string host = config["RabbitMq:Host"]!;
                    string username = config["RabbitMq:Username"]!;
                    string password = config["RabbitMq:Password"]!;
                    if (AppEnv.IsProduction)
                    {
                        host = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RABBITMQ_HOST")!;
                        username = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RABBITMQ_USER")!;
                        password = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RABBITMQ_PASSWORD")!;
                    }

                    configurator.Host(
                        new Uri(host),
                        hostConfigurator =>
                        {
                            hostConfigurator.Username(username);
                            hostConfigurator.Password(password);
                        }
                    );

                    configurator.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Interval(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));

                    configurator.Message<UserConfirmedEmailEvent>(e =>
                    {
                        e.SetEntityName("user-confirmed-email-event");
                    });
                    configurator.Publish<UserConfirmedEmailEvent>(e =>
                    {
                        e.ExchangeType = "fanout";
                        e.Durable = true;
                    });

                    configurator.ReceiveEndpoint(
                        $"user-confirmed-email-{applicationName}",
                        e =>
                        {
                            e.Durable = true;
                            e.AutoDelete = false;
                            
                            e.ConfigureConsumers(context);

                            e.Bind(
                                "user-confirmed-email-event",
                                b =>
                                {
                                    b.ExchangeType = "fanout";
                                    b.Durable = true;
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    );
                }
            );
        });

        return services;
    }
}


You have a client and server and the client should always be a master and the server always a slave.  You have the server as the master which is publishing data without a client requesting the info.  You design will never work properly.

@jdweng There's no client, like a fronted, involved in my scenario, both the publisher and consumer are separate Asp.Net Core applications working on the backend.

A connection needs two ends.  One end is a client which is the master and the other end is the server a slave.  The definition of client and server is different at the connection layer than at the computer layer.  Your backend has two ports.  One is a connection to the database where the backend is the client.  The 2nd connection the backend is a server to a client.  The 2nd one you have backwards and you have implemented a client instead of a server.

@jdweng Let's not use ambiguous terminology like client and server when referring to the messages' transmission, because these aren't frequently used terms in this case, a much better way would be to refer to those as publisher/subscriber or sender/consumer.
Can you please elaborate on what you meant by "you have implemented a client instead of a server"? If you're experienced in the messages' transmission matters and are able to help me, I can provide you my specific situation and describe how I'm trying to achieve reliable messaging.

I'm an EE and use the technical terminology.  Publisher sends automatically which is the root cause of the issue.  The real terms is client and listener (server).  Your terms are confusing because on one connection your can transmit in both direction.  There are 7 Network Layers and terms are different in each layer.  You are making an HTTP connection at the application layer which uses TCP as the Transport Layer.  Subscriber and Consumer are the Data Layer.

@jdweng Ok, let me explain my specific situation clearly. I have an endpoint in one microservice called ConfirmEmail, once this endpoint is hit and the business logic there approves the confirmation of email, an event (or message) called UserEmailConfirmedEvent is sent through MassTransit. The consumers of this event are: 1. the application that produced the event and 2. another microservice that needs the data of the user when their email is confirmed. The producer also should consume this event because the actual database update with the user's email set to "confirmed" happens in there

Where are you using the publisher?  No matter what you do you need a method for ACKing the data and track in the database the data was received.  You also need code to resend the data when no ACK was received.  If you use a publisher than the receiver has to publish the ACK.  Publisher are one way connections.  The other choice is to make a connection that is bi-directional so the receiver can ACK on the same connection.

I'm using my publisher inside the UserEmailConfirmed endpoint. What do you mean by ACK?
